# Improve on a 13-parameter constructor

Tags: c++, parameters, constructor

Thank Microsoft for Intellisense and Atomineer for Atomineer Utils...All of these parameters are *required and immutable*.

Is there a better way to do this?

```
/**************************************************************************************************
 * <summary>Initializes a new instance of the ADTBattleCharacter class.</summary>
 * <param name="name">         The name of the character.</param>
 * <param name="max_HP">       The maximum hit points.</param>
 * <param name="max_MP">       The maximum magic power.</param>
 * <param name="strength">     The strength.</param>
 * <param name="agility">      The agility.</param>
 * <param name="attack_power"> The attack power.</param>
 * <param name="defense_power">The defense power.</param>
 * <param name="gold">         The gold carried by the character.</param>
 * <param name="experience">   The experience the character is worth.</param>
 * <param name="stop_resist">  The character's resistance to stopspell.</param>
 * <param name="sleep_resist"> The character's resistance to sleep.</param>
 * <param name="hurt_resist">  The character's resistance to hurt/hurtmore.</param>
 * <param name="spell_list">   Available spells.</param>
 **************************************************************************************************/
ADTBattleCharacter(std::string name, unsigned char max_HP, unsigned char max_MP,
                   unsigned char strength, unsigned char agility,
                   unsigned char attack_power, unsigned char defense_power,
                   unsigned short gold, unsigned short experience,
                   double stop_resist, double sleep_resist, double hurt_resist,
                   std::bitset<SPELL_MAX> spell_list);
```

Comment: You can't pack them all into some container object and pass that instead?

Comment: Put em in a struct, give default values or base some off of others, change the ones you need, and pass the struct in?

Comment: @chris, that just punts the problem to the constructor of the struct. Doesn't really change anything.

Comment: @Mark: Why would the `struct` need a constructor? It's a *struct*; a collection of types. It's not an intelligent object; it's just a bag of stuff.

Comment: If you need to build such a complex object, and all these initial values are available in one place, then sure. Go for it and be happy! It's a grand opportunity to easily document a chunk of state in your program. The more common case is (of course) objects with a gazillion fields with zero or a small number of field values existing at creation time. The rest must be filled in as the object ages. This makes documenting the life cycle much harder. Embrace your good luck!

Comment: Just throw an exception in the object constructor if the struct doesn't have the required values. Or make defaults.

Comment: @NicolBolas, the point is that any solution appropriate for filling the struct is also appropriate for creating the object in the first place. Using a struct is an unnecessary intermediate step.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Looking at your specific case, it seems to me that you haven't broken things out very well.

Conceptually, a character in your system has:

- A name.
- A stat block, containing their basic stats (HP, defense, etc).
- The character's secondary attributes (experience).
- An inventory, which would include their current list of spells and their gold, among potentially other things.

That's 4 parameters, not 13. When you're writing a function, and you see that it's taking a large number of parameters, odds are good that some of those parameters are conceptually linked to each other. And odds are also good that *other* functions will want to use those linked parameters.

For example, you may want to display a character's stat block. Does the function that does this really need the *character*? No; it just needs the stat block. So it should take a stat block object.

Just like the character's constructor does.

Comment: +1 As Alan J Perlis said: "If you have a procedure with ten parameters, you probably missed some."

Comment: I see your point, but the "Replace Parameter with Object" refactor doesn't alleviate the problem, just moves it to another location. It may only be 4 in this constructor, but when those 4 classes' parameters are taken into account, it's still 13.

Comment: @Casey: So? 13 parameters spread over 4 classes is an average of 3.25 parameters per constructor. Is there a problem with having 4 parameters for a constructor? Do you consider a 4D vector dot-product function to take 8 parameters? No; it takes 2, which just so happen to have 4 values in each. Again, it's not just about *this* function; it's about the proper organization of data. A 4D vector is *one object*, no matter how many parameters its constructors take. Just as a stat block is a single object, no matter how many stats are in it.

Answer (score 1):

The better way is to use the [Builder design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern). Or, more simply, you can declare a class that contains fields for all the parameters to your current constructor. The parameter class can itself have a constructor (or constructors) that initialize the fields to reasonable default values, and you change the values by accessing the fields directly. Then either implement a function in the parameter class to construct your object, or define an object constructor that takes an instance of the parameter class.

Answer (score 0):

If the goal is just to reduce the number of arguments supplied to the constructor, there are many ways to achieve that. The real question is, as I understand it from the comments to my first post, is if there is an easier way to manage the parameters.

One way to make the parameters easier to manage is to use a general data structure to maintain them. Something like a map.

```
enum AttrTag { AT_Name, AT_Max_HP, AT_Max_MP, //...
               AT_Spells };

struct Attributes {
    typedef std::unique_ptr<AttrBase> AttrPtr;
    typedef std::map<AttrTag, AttrPtr> AttrMap;
    AttrMap attributes;

    template <AttrTag TAG>
    typename Attr<TAG>::value_type get_attr () const {
        AttrMap::const_iterator i = attributes.find(TAG);
        if (i != attributes.end()) return i->second->attr_cast<TAG>()->value;
        return Attr<TAG>::default_value;
    }

    template <AttrTag TAG>
    void set_attr (typename Attr<TAG>::value_type value) {
        attributes[TAG] = AttrPtr(new Attr<TAG>(value));
    }

    bool has_attr (AttrTag t) const {
        return attributes.find(t) != attributes.end();
    }

};
```

And it would be used like this:

```
Attributes attrs;
attrs->set_attr<AT_Gold>(100);
//...
ADTBattleCharacter(attrs);
//...
unsigned short g = attrs->get_attr<AT_Gold>();
```

The attributes would come off the `AttrBase` class that would know how to delegate to the actual attribute.

```
template <AttrTag> struct Attr;

struct AttrBase {
    virtual ~AttrBase () {}
    template <AttrTag TAG> Attr<TAG> * attr_cast () {
        return dynamic_cast<Attr<TAG> *>(this);
    }
};
```

And attributes would be created from specializing an `Attr` template that inherits from `AttrBase`.

```
template <AttrTag TAG>
struct Attr : public AttrBase {
    typedef unsigned char value_type;
    enum { default_value = 0 };
    value_type value;
    Attr (value_type v) : value(v) {}
};

template <>
struct Attr<AT_Name> : public AttrBase {
    typedef std::string value_type;
    static std::string default_value;
    value_type value;
    Attr (value_type v) : value(v) {}
};

template <>
struct Attr<AT_Gold> : public AttrBase {
    typedef unsigned short value_type;
    enum { default_value = 1 };
    value_type value;
    Attr (value_type v) : value(v) {}
};
```

This allows new attributes to be incrementally added without increasing the complexity of your constructor. In addition, the same collection of attributes could be passed to different entities, and each could react to only those attributes of interest to them. Only a subset of attributes need be set. The presence of an attribute can be tested, or a default value can be used. If you want to add and remove dynamic attributes, the container could be extended to do so by adding an additional map to hold them.

Comment: Please comment on a down vote, please, so I know what to fix. Thanks!

Comment: -1: This is *far worse*. At least with the constructor with many parameters, the parameters have reasonable names. Grouping attributes by their C++ basic type is functionally *meaningless*. If you're going to group them, then do it by something that actually means something.

Comment: It doesn't do anything to reduce the complexity and makes it more obscure.  It's better to pass a 'config' object or something that encapsulates the args.

Comment: @NicolBolas: I understand the concern, I was attacking the problem of number of parameters. My new post allows the attributes to be maintained in a queryable object.

Comment: @seand: Thank you for the feedback. I think my new post addresses it. Regards